# Connecting to AWS SES with Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

Currently working on a user registration form which (as expected) sends out an email to the registered user.

The client decided to go with AWS SES, so I have already had this configured.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Also defined the following credentials:

```
SES_KEY=keyRetrievedFromMyCredentialsInSES
SES_SECRET=passwordRetrievedFromMyCredentialsInSES
```

And also `telnet email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 587
Trying 52.19.235.197...
Connected to ses-smtp-eu-west-1-prod-345515633.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com.`

What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: Did you verify your `send` address in Amazon?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes that's verified.
Turns out that the issue was that I didn't set: 
`MAIL_DRIVER=ses`

Answer (score 1):

It may not working without `ADDRESS` and `NAME` setting.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=null
MAIL_PORT=null
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS = 'hello@example.com'
MAIL_FROM_NAME = 'Example'
```

After change setting in `.env`. Run `config:cache`:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation -> https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail

1. Install guzzle

```
    composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

2. Install AWS SDK for php (laravel)

```
    composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

3. Check values in .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=ses
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com  //aws SMTP Settings -> check mail host
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=smpt_username  //aws SMTP Settings -> click Create My SMTP Credentials
MAIL_PASSWORD=smpt_password  //aws SMTP Settings -> click Create My SMTP Credentials
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=your_email  //aws Email Addresses -> add email address -> send test email (in sendbox mode you can send email only on same email for testing) 
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= aws_access_key_id  //create user or in existing user check access key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= secret_access_key  //create user or in existing user check secret key
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1  //change with your region
AWS_BUCKET=
```

4. In config/service.php

```
'ses' => [
       'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
       'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
       'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'eu-west-1'), // change with your region
   ],
```

5. Clear cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```